# Vite + React app MIME error when reloaded the page

Tags: reactjs, heroku, vite, netlify

I have my react app + vite and i deployed it in netlify and my backend server is in heroku. it runs smoothly and have no issues with it. the main issue is that i have these 2 components that if i reloaded them, they only return blank white screen and the error message in the console is the MIME error. but everything else works perfectly fine without any issues. i have a fellow friend who did the same and have identical tech stacks used but our only difference is that they only used "create-react-app" not vite and they never encountered this issue. they said that we should redo all of the code and use create-react-app instead but i find it much tedious to do and i have been looking for another way to solve this issue. this is the error message that pops up whenever i reload a component:

"Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec"

we tried to change deployment sites such as cloudflare pages, but the problem persists and it is not even connected to heroku, so it means that the problem is in the frontend side of the app. i also think that the problem is in my nested routes, because those components are the ones that is causing the error except for the index element which is the /main component. here is my routes:

```
import Appointments from './components__dashboard/Appointments'
import Reports from './components__dashboard/Reports'
import EmailVerification from './EmailVerification'
import { Route, Routes, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AnimatePresence, AnimateSharedLayout } from 'framer-motion'

export default function AnimatedRoutes() {
    const location = useLocation()
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
        <Routes location={location} key={location.path}>
        <Route path='/' element={<HomePage/>} />
        <Route path='/signup' element={<SignUp/>}/>
        <Route path='/login' element={<LogIn/>}/>
        <Route path='/forgotpass' element={<ForgotPass/>}/>
        <Route path='/sched' element={<Sched/>}/>
        <Route path='/emailverification' element={<EmailVerification/>}/>
        <Route path='/slots' element={<Slots/>}/>
        <Route path='/thankyou' element={<ThankYou/>}/>
        <Route path='/adminlogin' element={<AdminLogIn/>}/>
        <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard/>}>
            <Route index element={<Main/>}/>
            <Route path='records' element={<Records/>}/>
            <Route path='rxdata' element={<RxData/>}/>
            <Route path='appointments' element={<Appointments/>}/>
            <Route path='reports' element={<Reports/>}/>
        </Route>
        </Routes>
    </AnimatePresence>
  )
}
```

the ones that are causing the MIME errors when reloaded are records and appointments component, the rxdata component is only being called inside the records component and the reports is currently hidden for the reason that its contents is moved to the main component.

Answer (score 0):

solved: turns out, i have a single line of code in vite.config.js that is not really included in there. my friend tried creating a new react app using vite and a single line of code is not present in his new app wherein it is in my app which is the base: './'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).